# Why does this function return undefined when run as a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet that will alter the styles of an interface I use daily, in order to make it easier to use.  However, when I begin the process of minifying the code I simply get the error of `undefined` in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my latest attempt.  Previous attempts are at the bottom.

```
javascript:void%20function(){var%20a=document.querySelectorAll(%22.btn%22);a.forEach(function(a){a.setAttribute(%22style%22,%22padding:%2015px%2025px%20!important;%22)})}();
```

Full:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');


matches.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute("style","padding: 15px 25px !important;");
});
```

Non URL-encoded bookmarklet:

```
javascript:void function(){var a=document.querySelectorAll(".btn");a.forEach(function(a){a.setAttribute("style","padding: 15px 25px !important;")})}();
```

Comment: JS entered in the URL bar (i.e. as a bookmarklet) will always return a value. Since you're using `void` here, it will force it to return undefined instead of anything else.

Comment: Thanks IceMetalPunk - I suppose I should rethink my question.  What I'd really like to know is why the styles aren't being applied!

Comment: Add code to log `matches` to the console.  Add code to log `item` to the console.  IMO you need to gather more diagnostic data to correctly conclude what the issue is, before you can set about fixing it.  We don't have the HTML you're running this against.  Does that page have buttons with a `.btn` class applied?  Are you running this with the console window open so you can observe any errors?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk it's returning undefined when I try it in the chrome dev tools console.  I of course removed the javascript:, void and anonymous function.

Comment: @Amy those were useful tips, but it isn't logging anything to the console right now for some reason.  To answer your other question: Yes there are always at least 1+ elements with the class ".btn" on them.  I've gotten this to work just a few minutes ago, but only from the console (not using the bookmarklet javascript:void function...).

Comment: Running the first line alone and console logging matches returns "false"...

Comment: `undefined` is no error o.O

Comment: _'Running the first line alone and console logging matches returns "false"'_ - That's not possible. `document.querySelectorAll()` will always return a `NodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarklet must return `undefined`, otherwise it won't execute the code properly (it may refresh the page, open the input instead of staying on the page etc). So `undefined` is not an error, it is a normal matter for any bookmarklet, and the only viable option.

The problem comes if the bookmarklet does not do what it is supposed to. As for your code, your **full code** that retrieves elements with className `'btn'` seems like **working**.

The issue is just the bookmarklet construction, it might be better to use **IIFE-construction**, i.e. Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```
javascript:(function () {
    /*code here*/
})();
```

Therefore, the working bookmarklet code is supposed to be like this:

```
javascript:(function () {
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    matches.forEach(function(item) {
        item.setAttribute('style','padding: 15px 25px !important;');
    });
})();
```

And you can copy-paste the code, without much worrying about spaces (like `%20`) or new lines; the code is supposed to get fixed itself upon inserting it as a bookmarklet.

PS: If someone wishes to make sure it works, you can substitute `document.querySelectorAll('*')` for `document.querySelectorAll('.btn')` to apply changes to everything and to see the result right away.

Here is an example:

```js
/*    javascript:(function () {*/
    var func1 = function(){
        var matches = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
        matches.forEach(function(item) {
            item.setAttribute('style','padding: 15px 25px !important;');
        });
    }
/*    })();*/
```

```html
<p><button id='id1' class='btn'>my button1</button></p>
<p><button id='id2' class='btn'>my button2</button></p>

<p><button id='id3' onclick=func1()>Press to Execute Code</p>
```